# O que seria um PID?

Tags: linux, terminologia, processo

Estou começando a estudar aplicações desktop. Tive uma determinada dúvida sobre como poderia saber se uma determinada aplicação está rodando e me disseram que eu poderia usar o *PID*, como uma solução, para poder detectar isso.

Eu costumo trabalhar com sistema operacional *Linux* e, pelo pouco que entendi, parece-me ser um ID de um processo. Seria isso mesmo?

Eu queria saber um pouco mais detalhes:

- O que seria o *PID*?
- Imaginando que o PID tenha a ver com a identificação do processo, se uma mesma aplicação for aberta duas vezes, ela terão *PID* iguais ou diferentes?
- Esse *PID* é coisa do Linux ou outros sistemas operacionais usam? Quer dizer, isso é um nome padrão ou algo adotado pelo Linux?

Comment: PID é o id do processo e é utilizado pelo sistema operacional. Cada processo tem um id diferente.

Comment: No windows também é usado, se você digitar `tasklist` no cmd ele traz os processos em execução: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp4X0.png sendo a segunda linha o PID

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> O que seria o PID?

O PID significa **P**rocess **ID**entification.

É um número que o kernel dá a cada processo para poder identificá-los.
É através do PID que podemos matar uma aplicação por exemplo.

> Imaginando que o PID tenha a ver com a identificação do processo, se uma mesma aplicação for aberta duas vezes, ela terão PID iguais ou diferentes?

Sempre que abrir uma segunda instância da aplicação ela receberá um novo PID. No caso especifico do Linux, existe até uma função chamada `fork` na linguagem C, que permite criar um novo processo e continuar a execução a partir do ponto que a função foi chamada. Ao chamar esta função, um novo PID é gerado.

> Esse PID é coisa do Linux ou outros sistemas operacionais usam? Quer dizer, isso é um nome padrão ou algo adotado pelo Linux?

O PID é um nome padrão adotado em todos os sistemas operacionais.Até onde eu conheço todos os sistemas operacionais atribuem PIDs aos processos existentes, sendo que geralmente o PID 1 é atribuído a um processo especial chamado de `init`.

No Windows 10 você pode ver o PID dos processos indo ao gerenciador de tarefas, na aba "Detalhes".

Caso não tenha a coluna PID, clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre qualquer coluna e selecione a opção "Selecionar Colunas". Marque a opção PID.